# What's the use of Picard's method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I was just taught about Picard's method for solving initial value problems (IVPs). So far what I did to solve an IVP was to solve the ode and then at the general solution I would substitute the initial condition. For example the IVP below could be solved like this:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y(t)$$ with $$y(0)=1$$

Then

$\int\frac{1}{y}dy=\int dt \Leftrightarrow  ln|y| = t+c_1 \Leftrightarrow  y(t) = \pm e^{t+c_1} \Leftrightarrow y(t)= \pm e^te^{c_1}$

Now let $c=c_1e^t$

$\Rightarrow y(t)=ce^t$

$y(0)=1 \Leftrightarrow ce^0=1 \Leftrightarrow c=1 \Rightarrow y(t)=e^t $

What's the point of using Picard's method in the IVP above, it seems to me that it just makes things more complicated...

What are some IVPs that Picard method is actually the best method?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "method", rather it is a "theorem", its importance is theoretical more than practical. I also agree with nmasanta that the paradigm of rewriting a differential equation as an integral one is successful, in mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picard's method of solving a differential equation (initial value problems) is one of successive approximation methods; that is, it is an iterative method in which the numerical results become more and more accurate, the more times it is used. Sometimes it is very difficult to obtain the solution of a differential equation.  In such cases, the approximate solution of given differential equation can be obtained.

Picard's iteration method was initially used to prove the existence of an initial value problem. Although this method is not of practical interest and it is rarely used for actual determination of a solution to the initial value problem (due to slow convergence and obstacles with performing explicit integrations), nevertheless, there are known some improvements in this procedure that make it practical. Picard's iteration method is important because it leads to an equivalent integral formulation useful in establishing many numerical methods. i.e.,

First order initial value problems of the form $$y'(x)=f(x,y(x))~,~~~~y(x_0)=y_0$$ can be
rewritten as an integral equation $$y(x)=y_0~+~\int_{x_0}^x~f(t,y(t))~dt~.$$
This integral formulation can be used to construct a sequence of approximate solutions to
the IVP. The basic idea is that given an initial guess of the approximate solution to the IVP, say$~\phi_0(x)~,$ an infinite sequence of functions, $~\{\phi_n(x)\}~$, is constructed according to the rule $$\phi_{n+1}(x)=y_0~+~\int_{x_0}^x~f(t,\phi_n(t))~dt~.$$
That is the $n^{\text{th}}$ approximation is inserted into the right hand side of the integral equation in place of the exact solution $~y(x)~$ and used to compute the $~(n+1)^{\text{st}}~$element of the sequence.

Also, Picard's iteration method helps in developing algorithmic thinking when the user implements it in a computer. It was the first method to solve analytically nonlinear differential equations. Working with Picard's iterations and its refinements helps everyone to develop computational skills.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, my book suggests it as a solution to the example I gave.. Which didn't make sense to me